# Get value from dynamic variable

Tags: javascript

I have variables such as `app.figures.data[0].user.x0` , `app.figures.data[0].user.y1`, and `app.figures.data[0].user.d2`. These variables were assigned values.

There are a dynamic number of these variables following the order of incrementing the final number in the variable (ie: The next variable after `app.figures.data[0].user.d2` is `app.figures.data[0].user.x3`).

I am trying to determine an efficient way to get the value of each variable dynamically in a loop.

```
    for(j = 0; j < len; j++){


            var x = 'x' + j;
            j++;

            var y = 'y' + j;
            j++;

           var d = 'd' + j;

           var dresult = app.figures.data[0].user.d;
}
```

I need the value of `dresult` as it was for `app.figures.data[0].user.d2`. For example, `app.figures.data[0].user.d2` is `23` so `dresult` should be `23` on that iteration.

I am new to JS so any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to increment `j` from _inside_ the loop? Also, post the whole code, including HTML, please.

Comment: Is `app.figures.data[0].user` an `Object` can't you simply use `Object.keys`?

Comment: @doutriforce Because I need to `app.figures.data[0].user.x`, `app.figures.data[0].user.y`, and `app.figures.data[0].user.d` to use at one time.

Comment: @Diego Can you please elaborate? An example would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @john yes an example would be really helpful

Comment: I have probably misunderstood your problem. Your issue is not with the variable names, it is with accessing them ordered. So nothing to do with `Object.keys`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the `[]` operator work for you?

```
for (let j = 2; j < len; j += 3) {
  let dresult = app.figures.data[0].user['d' + j];
}
```

Comment: should it be for (let j = 2; j < len; j += 3) ? There is no d0.

Comment: Yes you are perfectly right. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var values=["x0","y1","d2"]. map(el=>this[el],app.figures.data[0].user);
```

It will map the keys to their corresponding values.
You can put that in a loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<100;i+=3){
      var values=["x","y","d"]. map((el,id)=>this[el+(i+id)],app.figures.data[0].user);

     values.forEach(console.log);//just an example case
}
```

Some explanations: i is the counter, incremented by 3, stops at 102. el is an array element, so "y", and id is the index in that array. this is the user object. So this[el+(i+id)] gets the value of this objects property.

By the way *dynamic variable names* are really bad style and will cause many bugs. May change your code to work without it.